# MongoDB with EclipseLink, unsupported annotations

Tags: java, mongodb, jpa, nosql, eclipselink

I must replace Oracle by MongoDB with EclipseLink, i've read in this article :

[EclipseLink with NoSQL](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.7/concepts/nosql003.htm)

That somme annotations are not supported such as @SequenceGenerator, @JoinTable and @OrderBy

I dont found how to replace them in the article, what is the solution or best alternative for these annotations ?

Ex :

```
@SequenceGenerator(name="GEN_SEQ", sequenceName="GEN_SEQUENCE", allocationSize=50)
```

Thank's

Comment: replace them ? just delete them perhaps? Since JPA is a specification for RDBMS only then it makes perfect sense that many of those JPA annotations are of no relevance to non-RDBMS datastores

Comment: this is very hard, or impossible move. No transactions, totally different sense of "integrity", lack of relations. Unacceptable for financial

Comment: What is kind of system? If money are problems, many people say migrate from Oracle SQL to PostgreSQL